# Trigger recalculation before printing

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file which uses a user defined function which is rather slow. Therefore the recalculation option is set to manual because otherwise editing values in the file would be painfully slow.

In order to prevent the user to print a sheet with outdated (non recalculated) data, I'd like Excel to trigger a recalculation of the sheet before it lauches the printing process.

Is there a way to tell Excel to call some user defined function just before printing.

```
' Function to be called before printing
Public Sub RecalculateBeforePrinting()
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    call RecalculateBeforePrinting()
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works like a charme. Now I'd need the same but for print preview but I haven't found anything such as `Workbook_BeforePrintPreview`. `Workbook_BeforePrint` is not called when I press the print preview button in the title bar. I'm using Excel 2010.